# Diff-Tool that can autoformat source code before comparing?

Tags: java, eclipse, diff, autoformatting

I've been using WinMerge, Eclipse's compare tool and Tortoise's to see my changes before committing. The problem is that when I edit a file that hasn't been edited by someone else since we last updated our autoformatter-configuration I'll see many, many changes caused by the autoformatter.
Now I have to copy the code from the previous revision, autoformat it in Eclipse and copy it into WinMerge to only see I really made.

Is there a tool that can automatically autoformat both versions of the file I'm comparing?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I find that setting your diff to "ignore whitespace" fixes (for me at least) the bulk of the underlying troubles (reformat makes all lines go 'changed'). Maybe that's a help?

Comment: Ignoring whitespace sadly only fixes about 10% of the 'false' positives.

Comment: Yes, check out http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2007/08/18/eclipse-cvs-compare/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any diff tool that allows you to set up an external conversion before the comparison should handle that.  External conversions are primarily intended for things like Word/Excel/PDF to Text conversion, but you can do anything you want as long as you can run it from the command line.

For **Beyond Compare** we already have an [optional add-on rule](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformats_alt) that will use [Jalopy](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/) to format Java source and another one that use HTML Tidy for HTML files.

**WinMerge** doesn't look like it supports a Java reformatter out of the box, but their [plugins](http://manual.winmerge.org/Plugins.html) page does describe how you could add one using a dll or Windows Scripting Host scriptlet.

Comment: Thanks, writing a prediff-plugin for WinMerge that calls Eclipse's commandline formatter seems like the perfect solution.

Comment: @Robber Do you happen to have this plugin still? Would save me some time :)